# When to use an integrated filter?

Tags: passive-filter

I have recently run across integrated passive filter network chips such as the [IP4251](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/IP4251_52_53_54-TTL.pdf).

How do I know when I need something like this? In my day to day life I would probably say okay, this IO needs such and such filter cap or decoupling cap. I would never have said, however, that I need a specialized filter package, nor have I ever seen a datasheet that recommends one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the datasheet shows an example of SD card interfaces, MMC interfaces, etc. I'd suspect these are used in general on fast data lines to control the edge transitions and meet EMI requirments.

How would you know if you need one? Failing an EMI test would be indicator.

Keep in mind that datasheet examples and recommendations are not sufficient for a functioning system that works at all the edge cases.

Comment: But it still begs the question of why these over hand matched discretes?

Comment: Cheaper, of course.